# Is $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R})$ subspace topology of $(V, B(V))$?

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be a real separable Hilbert space with norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_V$.

Denote $\mathcal{B}(V)$ be the topology generated by the metric $d_V(x,y)=\Vert x-y \Vert$ on $V$.

Suppose that
$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ be the borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb{R}$
(smallest sigma algebra containing all open sets of $\mathbb{R}$).

Im thinking, if restricted on $R$ the metric on $V$ is simply the natural distance considered on $R$. Can we say that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \mathcal{B}(V)$ as a subspace topology?, that is,
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\{A\cap \mathbb{R}: A \in \mathcal{B}(V)\}?$$

Comment: $A$ is a subset of $V$. What is  the meaning of $A \cap \mathbb R$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  $A\cap \mathbb{R}= \{x\in V : x\in \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: That makes  no sense. A real number cannot be an element of $V$.  I hope my answer below clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 2):

To identify $\mathbb R$ as  a subset of $V$ take a unit vector $x$ and consider the a map $f: \mathbb R \to V$  defined by $f(t)=tx$. This is a  homeomorhism from $\mathbb R$  onto the one dimensional subspace $M$ generated by $x$. Hence $B$ is Borel in $\mathbb R$  iff $f(B)$ is Borel in $M$. Use the fact that $M$ is closed in $V$ to conclude that $B$ is Borel in $\mathbb R$  iff $f(B)$ is Borel in $V$. This finishes the proof.

For the question in the title the answer is YES because $f$ is a  homeomorphism.